# How to achive Join scenario in Google Datastore ndb(Python library)

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have two kinds:

```
class Professor(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

class Student(ndb.Model):
    professor = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Professor)
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

I want to find all the Student entities where Professor name is "Snape". How can I do this?

Or if I take the "One To Many" example of https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling. Then I want to find all the PhoneNumber entities where Contact.name is "scott". How to do this.

The appengine example only tells how to filter on PhoneNumber attributes. What if I want to filter on the related Kind, i.e Contact attributes.

Comment: This question is a little broad for Stack Overflow.  I would recommend posting this on [App Engine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) to get a more appropriate best-practices type of discussion.  I'd also suggest including some examples of what approaches you've tried or considered.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would recommend using an [`ndb.KeyProperty`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#iterators) as a property of the student model to refer to a given professor.

```python
class Professor(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Student(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  prof = ndb.KeyProperty()
```

With the above entity kinds, one could query for all professors whose name is "Snape" using a key-only query, and subsequently query for all students whose prof is [one of the retrieved keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#neq_and_in).

```python
prof_keys = Professor.query().fetch(100, keys_only=True)

if len(prof_keys) < 1:
  print "Cannot a given professor's students"
  return

students = Student.query(Student.prof.IN(prof_keys)).fetch(100)

if len(students) < 1:
  print "Found no students whose professor is Snape"
  return

for student in students:
  print "Found student named {} whose professor is Snape".format(student.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
# professor model
class Professor(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

# student model
class Student(ndb.Model):
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    age = ndb.IntegerProperty()

snape = ndb.Key(Professor, 'snape')
Professor(name="Professor Snape", email="snape@blah.edu", key=snape).put()


st1 = Student(name="Akshar", age=18, parent=snape)
st2 = Student(name="Greg", age=19, parent=snape)
st3 = Student(name="Alex", age=18, parent=snape)

st1.put()
st2.put()
st3.put()

# so lets say give me all students that has class with Professor Snape
for student in Student.query(ancestor=snape).fetch(10):
    print student.name

# You should get something:
Akshar
Greg
Alex
```

Comment: But this approach has limitations on number of students a professor can have, right? This restricts us to 1MB size for Professor?

Comment: Per transaction you have limits 10mb to push to datastore and that is a lot! Most of others APIs are not close to 10MB. It all depends on what kind of model you have but for example my model in 10mb I could push ~20k records. That example is right approach. Take a look at my comments here even somebody downgraded it but cover base   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43925030/google-cloud-datastore-only-store-unique-entity/43945541#43945541